# Android Register BroadcastReceiver to run continously

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to implement a minimal screen activity logger app. So, the application should run on the background (no user interaction) and it will log the screen on and off activities. I have started these codes, but it seems that I need to register my `ScreenBroadcastReceiver` `broadcastreceiver`. If I do it with the below code in main activity, it works. However, I do not want to register it in main because the user cannot launch the activity every time. So, where should i register my `BroadcastReceiver` so that the application works without user interaction?

`oncreate` in main activity

```
    //I need to find another place to put these code, Where ???
    //IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    //filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    //BroadcastReceiver screenOnReceiver = new ScreenBroadcastReceiver();
    //registerReceiver(screenOnReceiver, filter);
```

This is ScreenBroadcastReceiver, it will be triggered when the screen is on.

```
public class ScreenBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        Log.w("OnReceive", "SCREEN IS ON");
        }
    }

}
```

This is the BootReceiver to run the program on the background itself.

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, ScreenListenerService.class);
        context.startService(service);

            //IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
            //filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        //BroadcastReceiver screenOnReceiver = new ScreenBroadcastReceiver();
        //context.registerReceiver(screenOnReceiver, filter);
    }

}
```

This is the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

 <service android:name=".ScreenListenerService"></service>

 <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**Update:**

I added a service, but it does not work. Did i forget to add something? or what ?

```
public class ScreenListenerService extends Service {

    public void OnCreate(){

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        BroadcastReceiver screenOnReceiver = new ScreenBroadcastReceiver();
        registerReceiver(screenOnReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

use [Service](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html&ei=U5Z8Ua6nOcv9rAf39YCQBA&usg=AFQjCNFwa_Qocx5ioFUPcqlqaUfnTYRndQ&bvm=bv.45645796,d.bmk) for your purpose and do the same as you did in the activity.

Comment: thanks, i added a service and did the same, but not working. can you check the update?

Comment: I meant ,, use broadcastreceiver with service instead of using with activity.

Comment: yes, I did it. I no longer use the code in the main activity. but still no success....

Comment: ok then, let me know your problem clearly.. what do you exactly want> do you want to start a service when boot completed?

Comment: yes, it should run at anytime and if the screen is on, it should print log("screen is on")

Comment: try this, if the onreceive of bootreceiver trigerred then start the service. within the service register the other receiver

Comment: I replaced the code in 'bootreceiver' with Intent service = new Intent(context, ScreenListenerService.class);
     context.startService(service);

Comment: Use service to register screenOnReceiver and start service inside oncreate of mainactivity and also start service on bootupcomplete and register bootupcomplete broadcastreceiver thr main.xml not thr code k

Comment: I am not gonna use main activity. I cannot depend on the onreate of main activity. I should handle with the service.

Comment: so when app is started u dont require service is running?

Comment: the end goal is to log all screen on/off events without user interaction.